# onclick Select's option tag strangly trigger even without click on option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-events

I have a code like this:

```js
    <select id='chapter'>
        <option onclick="return my_function('1')" value='1'>1</option>
        <option onclick="return my_function('2')" value='2'>2</option>
        <option onclick="return my_function('3')" value='3'>1</option>
    </select>
```

When user click on select it trigger one of options `onclick` events.
I really don't know what to do.
Here is my code in work and see problem(check select tags):

http://animup.net/manga/claymore/c127/#1

Comment: I think you can't put `oncllick` event at option tag.

Comment: It makes sense since you got 3 options and when user clicks on select, one of the 3 options will be clicked on. There are much better ways of handling this and I am sure the jquery answer will be pouring in soon

Comment: it would be better to return the index of the selected option in a click or change event on the select

Comment: @RUJordan as long as it works I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mayabelle said, use the `onchange` event. However, I don't like inline JS. It's bad practice and ugly. Use an MVC approach and separate your code, using `addEventListener` to attach an event and function (can be predefined, can be anonymous)

```
<select id='chapter'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>1</option>
</select>

var x = document.getElementById("chapter");
x.addEventListener("change",function() {
    var value = my_function(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
),false);
```

Comment: @Curiosity separating the HTML markup (view) from the JS functionality (controller)

Comment: That's literally the definition of MVC. "MVC (Model-View-Controller) is an architectural design pattern that encourages improved application organization through a separation of concerns."

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is an onChange event.

Try this:

```
<select id='chapter' onChange="SelectOption(this)">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>1</option>
</select>

function SelectOption(sel) {
    var selectedValue = sel.value;
    // Do something with selectedValue here, e.g. call function1 if value 1 is selected
}
```